# How to find the mortality rate for certain countries in a csv given population and total deaths

Tags: python

[image: csv file]

('population') is in a further column.

In this csv file I want to find the mortality rate for specific countries and print it

So far for the mortality equation i have this

```
`mortality = ((data_dict['total_deaths'])/(data_dict['population'])) * 100

'print("This countries mortality rate is ", mortality(data_dict['location']))
```

And am getting this error

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
```

~

```
\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_10536/3680333997.py in <module>
      8 
      9 mortality = ((data_dict['total_deaths'])/(data_dict['population'])) * 100
---> 10 print("This countries mortality rate is ", mortality(data_dict['location']))
     11 

TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable'
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.   Your ```mortality``` value is a ```ndarray```.  I think you want ```mortality[data_dict["location"]]``` instead.

Comment: @ewong 
Thanks for your reply
That leaves me with this

`---> 10 print("This countries mortality rate is ", mortality[data_dict['location']])
     11 

IndexError: arrays used as indices must be of integer (or boolean) type`

Comment: Then clearly my understanding is limited.  I defer to others.  Sorry for my wrong suggestion.

Comment: I think you'll need to provide more details. In any case, one thing remains clear: `mortality` is not a function, it's an array, so you need to use it like an array. I suggest you just print `mortality` itself, inspect it and try to understand its structure, that might let you figure out how to index or slice it to extract the information you're looking for.